# RealTek Wireless adapter issues. (RTL8192ce and RTL8192cu)

Tags: wireless, 14.04, rtl8192ce

I have been having significant issues with the usability/reliability of my wireless cards. I have tried several fixes over the past few days. I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I go from 1/10 of the speed i should be getting to not working at all. It does drop sometimes as well.  (The above is in regards to my PCI RTL8192ce card)

I recently tried to install a usb wifi adapter (RTL8192cu) and I cannot even get that one to connect well enough to use. ( basically shows no "bars" on the wireless icon on the top right)

I have tried to install the realtek drivers from the  realtek site but I had a couple errors with the install. (I have the output somewhere if it is needed.) I have tried as well to use the fix found here: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7  to no avail.  I would appreciate your assistance in fixing this. (There may be a question already solving this but I have tried 2-4 fixes over the past 2 days and none worked)

Comment: The Q&A mentions the exact card model for 14.04 thus this is probably a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/414974/realtek-rtl8192ce-wireless-slow-intermittent-access?rq=1

Comment: That was actually the one I tried right before making this post. It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: @fossfreedom In regards to the PCI card that link may help but the USB card will not work without installing one of the available versions from github.

Answer (score 7):

It's a driver issue.

You might want to check out this thread. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2148130&page=2

https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

COPIED FROM GITHUB:

Ensure you have the necessary prerequisites installed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

Clone this repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install it:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

And reboot. You're done.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, can you please incorporate the essential parts of the answer into the question? Links have a nasty habit of going bad.

Comment: I've copied verbatim now

Comment: Do I have to rebuild this driver after kernel updates?

Comment: @tvn No, DKMS takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issues, until I installed the DKMS driver via https://github.com/vincent-t/rt8192cu_dkms

My 8192cu is fast and stable since that driver was installed.

Comment: The installation procedure for this solution is much more automated than the other solution suggested on this page. One command `sudo make install_dkms` is all what is required for installation.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with connecting rtl8192ce (EdiMax EW-7612PIn V2) from my ubuntu 14.04. Actually the issue was only with APs not supporting N draft (so the old b/g standard). I checked three different boxes and all had the same issue. I had however no issues with the one AP that had N-draft support.
The problem was that the default bitrate with old APs was always set to 1Mb/s even though the link quality was 70/70. But I was not even able to ping default gw. So the solution was to issue:

```
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 rate auto
```

Unfortunately I do not see an option in ubuntu NetworkManager to specify bitrate (I do not use configuration from /etc/network/interfaces) so I added the iwconfig command to

```
/etc/init.d/wifirifi
```

and issued

```
chmod ugo+rx
update-rc.d wifirifi defaults
```