# Wi-Fi network does not connect right after system started, but it works after restart

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, router

Wi-Fi network does not connect right after system started, but when I restart my router it becomes working well without failures. What can be a cause of this problem?
P.S. Such behavior was noticed on every device such as tablet, smartphone, PC (Linux/Windows).
**Router model:** tl-wr740n/tl-wr740nd
**Other info:** http://paste.ubuntu.com/14545476/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was not consistent with all devices, I would say that this is might be a driver issue. The RTL8192CU does have a history of issues with a few linux kernel versions.
However, you might want to take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471208/realtek-wireless-adapter-issues-rtl8192ce-and-rtl8192cu).

I would suggest to change the TKIP encryption into AES and switch to WPA2 instead of WPA.

*** Update ***
Sorry I missed that you're using CCMP. 
However, I have noticed that there are two other networks in the area that use the same channel(11) that you are using. Try to change it to 8 or 6 and see how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, I had an issue with rtl8192cu bug, but I resolved it with new drivers. And btw, I have CCMP encryption and WPA2 security.

Comment: Seems the idea with channel works. Thanks, probably forgot to check this.

Comment: ...or it's not. Still can't acess connection after startup.

Comment: Did you delete the network from the PC and re-add it after changing the channel?

Comment: Is it necessary? Because after changing a channel it asked me just to restart the router.