# Failing to install driver for wireless pci card

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I installed a wireless PCI adapter (Edimax N300) and it was working right away albeit not very good. In my quest to improve perfomance I made a mistake and followed this 
guide (under 6): [RealTek Wireless adapter issues. (RTL8192ce and RTL8192cu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471208/realtek-wireless-adapter-issues-rtl8192ce-and-rtl8192cu)
basically installing the wrong driver for "cu" instead of "ce". After the reboot the card was not detected (at least I got no indication of any wireless connections around and there were plenty before). Since then I failed trying to install several drivers to get the card runnning again.

I download the respective archives and then do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
makes
sudo make install
```

I get an error at the "make"-stage which reads as follows (apologies for the German):

```
make
make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-56-generic/build M=/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-56-generic« wird betreten
CC [M]  /home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o
In file included from /home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:39:0:
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/pci.h:247:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
int __devinit rtl_pci_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev,
           ^
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:365:4: error: ‘struct ieee80211_hw’ has no member named ‘channel_change_time’
hw->channel_change_time = 100;
^
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:885:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
   rx_status.freq = hw->conf.channel->center_freq;
                            ^
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:886:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
   rx_status.band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                            ^
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_beacon_statistic’:
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1160:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘compare_ether_addr’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
if (compare_ether_addr(hdr->addr3, rtlpriv->mac80211.bssid))
^
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1451:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
info->band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                    ^
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_store_debug_level’:
/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1684:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strict_strtoul’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
ret = strict_strtoul(buf, 0, &val);
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/kai/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis »/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-56-generic« wird verlassen
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I managed. Here is what I did: Open terminal, type "gksudo nautilus", go to folder "etc/modprobe.d" and opened "blacklist-native-rtl8192". Then I put a "##" in front of every line (so that they are not processed).