# Is it possible to convert Ubuntu 15.10 to 15.04LTS?

Tags: wireless

I upgraded to 16.04 last night to discover I've got no WiFi working on it. I whacked my 15.10 disc back in and reinstalled old reliable. However, from my understanding, 15.10 goes out of support in a couple months. I was wondering if there is a way to use the command line to convert 15.10 to 15.04LTS so I can stick with what I know works for a while.

If this is impossible, would anyone possibly be able to help me with my 16.04 WiFi problems? I'm using a Realtek RTL8192CU USB WiFi adaptor. Worked fine out of the box with 15.10. How can I get it working again? I might be wrong by 16.04 and 15.xx seek very similar, so wouldn't my old drivers work? I just don't know how to get it working.

If anyone can solve either issue for me, I'll be a happy fella.

Peace! x

Comment: There is no 15.04LTS did u mean 14.04LTS???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RealTek Wireless adapter issues. (RTL8192ce and RTL8192cu)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471208/realtek-wireless-adapter-issues-rtl8192ce-and-rtl8192cu)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: no, there is no simple way to downgrade your system; upgrading is a one-way road. (Of course, you could reinstall 15.04 completely from scratch, though.)

To your second question: I'm seeing people with Realtek wifi hardware reporting success on 16.04 (and other versions) with the following instructions (just run these commands one-by-one in a terminal). You'll need some sort of internet connection temporarily, such as an ethernet cable attached to your router, to download the packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```