# Ubuntu 16.04 - Wireless adapter is timing out (rtl8192cu)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, adapter

I've been having problems with my wireless adapter just stopping connectivity with my network at random. This usually occurs when I have not had any internet activity for several minutes. Once this happens I am not able to access the internet for an undefined amount of time (usually 2-5 minutes) until the system "decides" to resume activity (I am not sure how this happens on a technical level).

Notably the bit rate goes from the operational 72.2 Mb/s to 7 Mb/s. Running the command `lshw-C` network yields the chipset `rtl8192cu`. Additionally at the occurrence of the time-out I get these messages through `dmesg`

```
[  651.204177] perf interrupt took too long (2523 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 1085.185940] perf interrupt took too long (5026 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
```

and upon disconnecting the usb device (during the drop-out behaviour) I receive:

```
[ 2755.028193] rtl_usb: reg 0x102, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x69543425
[ 2755.028198] rtl_usb: reg 0x422, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x3d30a78
[ 2755.028202] rtl_usb: reg 0x542, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x2203dd
[ 2755.028209] rtl_usb: reg 0x1cc, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x18
```

I have been able to remedy this through an unorthodox solution of creating a bash script consisting of a while loop that pings a website (using google.com but in practice it could be any web address) thus retaining network activity and preventing this timing out behavior. What is really causing this and is it simply a hardware incompatibility with Ubuntu or can I solve this through other means?

I've also taken a look at the suggested questions list and came up with these pages:

[RealTek Wireless adapter issues. (RTL8192ce and RTL8192cu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471208/realtek-wireless-adapter-issues-rtl8192ce-and-rtl8192cu)

https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

Another option is this link:

https://github.com/vincent-t/rt8192cu_dkms

The good news is that from looking at the first github page, my specific device is supported (WN823N). However I'm hesitant in installing what seem to be very outdated drivers from an older OS. Should I go ahead with the install?

Answer (score 0):

The support for your device has been added to the new kernel. Just use Ubuntu zesty.

Comment: In that case a newer kernel would suffice since Xenial is an LTS release.

Comment: @DavidFoerster A LTS release would not get a newer linux.

Comment: Not automatically, but there's a simple and well supported path to get a newer kernel and broader hardware support in LTS releases through the [hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus) without a release upgrade.